# How do I implement Apple's guidance for shared Extension code in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-extensions

The Apple Extension guidance has this document on [Using an embedded framework to share code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

I want to share code between my Extension, and the hosting application. How do I implement the following within an Xamarin app:

- Require Only App-Extension-Safe API
- You must choose “Frameworks” as the destination for your embedded framework in the Copy Files build phase.

Comment: first hit on Google: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

> Require Only App-Extension-Safe API

Currently there is nothing in the code review/analysis or compile phase within `Xamarin.iOS` that will warn or prevent APIs that are not allowed within Extensions,

i.e. There are `TODO` notes within the [healthkit.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/38148c718a2d0ec70496959a86a6bee756ae7f28/src/healthkit.cs):

```
// FIXME NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE("Not available to extensions") ;
```

It currently is up to the C# developer to follow Apple's Guidelines. Obviously the following would cause an app to be rejected if this was within Extension code:

```
var a = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication;
```

But the **Some APIs Are Unavailable to App Extensions** list provided by Apple is fairly concise on what is not allowed:

- [Understand How an App Extension Works](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6)

**Personally** For code sharing purposes I add a compiler directive to my Extension projects to conditional compile code that I need to remove... ("NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS", just like what is available in ObjC/Swift Extension projects)